# console not returning expected number of characters in cin buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

I am creating a console version of "Bull Cow Game". In the game, the user has a certain number of tries to guess what the secret word is. Every time they guess, the program returns the number of "Bulls" and "Cows" they guessed correctly. The user gets a "Bull" for every character that they guess in the right place and a "Cow" for every character that they guess correctly but is not in the right place.

My problem is in my getGuess() function. In the do-while loop, the program is supposed to loop if the user inputs anything other than the number of characters in "answer". When I run my program, I get some unexpected and confusing results:

1) No matter what I input for the **first** "guess", the program tells me that cin's gcount() is 0 or 1 characters after setw(). I could input 50 characters or 2 and the program would output the same result. If the gcount is 1, then this counts as one of the allotted guesses which is an undesirable result. If the cin.gcount() is 0, the program correctly does not count the guess as valid but I am still confused as to why the cin.gcount() is 0 at all.

2) If I change the number of characters in my guess from the **previous** guess, the program tells me that the cin.gcount() is whatever the cin.gcount() was after the **previous** guess instead of after the current guess. This is also an undesirable result since if the user decides to input the correct number of characters, the program will not accept the user's guess as valid.

I am confused as to why this is happening since isn't cin.ignore() supposed to dump all of the extraneous characters that setw() doesn't accept? Why would the number of characters in the cin buffer carry over from one guess to the other?

Here is the function in question:

```
string getGuess()
{
    string guess = "";

    const int MAX_LENGTH = 4; 

    /*ensures that "guess" is the same length as answer. This
    will make it so that the program avoids comparing "guess"
    to "answer" if "guess" has more characters than "answer".
    This do-while loop also ensures that a user can't overflow
    the cin buffer by theoretically inputting more characters
    than the buffer could contain*/

    bool endLoop = false; 

    do {
        cout << "Enter a word containing exactly " << MAX_LENGTH << " characters: ";

        cin >> setw(MAX_LENGTH) >> guess;

        cout << "cin.gcount() after setw(): " << cin.gcount() << " characters" << endl;

        /*ensures that the only character in the cin is '\n'. Otherwise
        do-while loop continues*/
        if (cin.gcount() != 1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid number of characters. Please input exactly " << MAX_LENGTH 
<< " characters" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
        endLoop = true; 
        }

        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout << "cin.gcount() after cin.ignore(): " 
<< cin.gcount() << " characters" << endl;

        cout << "guess: " << guess << endl;

        cout << endl; 

       } while ( endLoop == false );


    cout << endl;


    return guess; 
}
```

Note: This was compiled with Microsoft Visual C++, ISO standard c++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of misunderstandings I think

1) [gcount](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) only tells you how many characters have been read after an *unformatted input operation*, `cin >> guess` is not an unformatted input operation.

2) `setw` on input does not limit the numbers of characters read. If less than the specified width characters are read then the input is padded to make it equal the given width, but it does not stop more characters being read.

Your code is too tricky, forget about fancy I/O operations, do it the straightforward way. Just read a line of characters into a string using `getline` and check if the characters entered are what you expect. For instance remove the spaces at the beginning and end of that string, then check for internal spaces and finally check if the string is the length you require.